# Как использовать MAT с Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk, утечка-памяти

Я установил MAT,выгрузил HEAP из Android Device Monitor и теперь у меня есть .hprof файл, как его проанализировать в MAT?

Comment: Стоит заметить, что Android Studio имеет [свой внушительный набор](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/528229/177345) инструментов для профилирования, что что а утечки без труда можно выловить.

Comment: @pavlofff я начинающий, а в интернете в основном по этой теме были примеры с использованием MAT, потому я задался этим вопросом. И еще MAT вроде точно показывает где происходит утечка(какой класс и прочее), разве в Android Studio есть средство с подобным функционалом?

Comment: 1, 2, и 3 пункт по ссылке выше. Анализатор там тоже есть. Описание инструментов по ссылкам в ответе.

Comment: @pavlofff спасибо, буду знать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Что бы конвертировать .hprof выгруженный из Android Studio в MAТобразный .hprof необходимо проделать следующие действия.

1. Открываем командную строку и идем в папку Android\sdk\platform-tool
2. Затем вводим команду hprof-conv "путь к конвертируемому файлу" "путь к итоговому файлу" у меня это выглядело так:

C:\Users\sh_am\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools> hprof-conv "C:\Users\sh_am\Desktop\rambotv30.hprof" "C:\Users\sh_am\Desktop\4mat.hprof"

3. Это создаст файл стандартный .hprof файл с именем которое вы указали у меня это 4mat.hprof

Открывал файл в MAT все работает отлично