# Как освобождать память используя Picasso (OutOfMemoryError)

Tags: android, picasso, outofmemoryerror

В проекте очень много изображений (банеры, фотографии и прочее прочее).
Все грузиться через интернет, использую библиотеку Picasso.

Периодически приложение вылетает с ошибкой - OutOfMemoryError

Есть ли способы высвобождать память при смене активити?
Или какие либо еще решения с данной библиотекой?

Спасибо!

Comment: У вас либо память течет (memory leak), либо в какой-то момент вы пытаетесь загрузить слишком большое изображение. В любом случае - надо смотреть в код.

Comment: Скорее всего проблема не в количестве изображений, а плохой оптимизации самого приложения: утечки памяти в коде (неиспользуемые объекты не уничтожаются из-за ошибок в архитектуре), неоптимизированые ресурсы (использование изображений, превышающих разрешение экрана), неоптимизированные разметки (многократная вложенность контейнеров) и тп. Пройдитесь профилировщиками  и устраняйте действительные проблемы оптимизации,а не следствия. Не думаю, что при должной оптимизации будут нехватки памяти при любом разумном количестве изображений

Comment: Для поиска действительной проблемы Android Studio имеет хороший [набор инструментов](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/528229/177345) для профилирования

Answer (score 1):

Нашел пару вещей которые значительно улучшили ситуацию:

1. Использовать skipMemoryCache() хоть он и устарел.
2. Использовать Builder для создания экземпляра.
3. Минимизировать создания новых экземпляров Picasso.

Возможно есть еще какие то решения и рекомендации. Но это улучшило ситуацию.