# OutOfMemoryError андроид

Tags: java, android, outofmemoryerror

Использую в приложении несколько фрагментов, и при долгом  переходе между фрагментами вылетает ошибка OutOfMemoryError.

Подскажите, как отловить ошибку? Как я понял - это утечка памяти?

Comment: скинь полный трейс

Comment: Android Studio имеет хороший [набор инструментов](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/528229/177345) для профилирования