# allocated heap size индикатор показан для устройства?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Вот на скриншоте в правом нижнем углу я отметил

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я понял что показано количество израсходованной хип памяти.

Только не пойму это память на конкретном подключенном устройстве имеется ввиду?

Comment: Это память, занимаемая самой студией. По инструментам профилирования приложения на устройстве\эмуляторе смотрите [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/528229/177345)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это память, выделенная JVM на вашем компьютере самой студии. 
Android Studio, как на странно, тоже написана на `Java`

Comment: аа понял) Спасибо! А я могу как то влиять на это показатель? или это просто информация для общего сведения?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko вы можете указать параметры выделяемой для студии памяти, [отредактировав файл vmoptions](https://extremegtx.wordpress.com/2015/01/08/android-studio-speed-up-studio-and-gradle/) в каталоге студии (первый пункт по ссылке)