# Сколько весит объект в java?

Tags: java, android

Есть в проекте одна проблема, которая решается двумя способами. Но я не могу оценить какой способ будет "дешевле" для памяти.

Как корректно вычислить на Android устройстве, сколько весят те или иные объекты в java?

P.S. В одном случае это массив `List` из других объектов, которые в свою очередь содержат другие объекты, в другом это `subscriber` из Rx.

P.S.2: Возможно есть какие то другие способы оценки скорости работоспособности или занимаемой объектами памяти, помимо тривиального вычисления разниц в затрачиваемом времени/памяти до и после в обоих случаях?

Comment: 1. вычислять каждый тип данных. 2. использовать Java-agent для просмотра объектов в памяти и их размер.

Comment: @pavlofff судя по ссылке это то что нужно! Спасибо большое. Оформите пожалуйста в качестве ответа что бы могли закрыть мой вопрос!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android Studio включает [ряд инструментов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/528229/177345) для профилирования приложения. Они помогут оценить выделяемую приложению и его объектам память, содержимое "кучи", производительность, нагрузку на устройство и др. при выполнении программы.

Вам нужно профилировать оба варианта и сравнить результаты.