# Поиск и определение участка кода в котором происходит утечка памяти

Tags: java, android, android-studio, книги, утечка-памяти

Вопрос общего характера - как найти утечку памяти? Есть ли какие нибудь хорошие гайды? Можно на английском. Библиотеку leack canary не советуйте, т.к. она не видит утечку. Проявляется утечка в следующем: открываю приложение, никак не взаимодействую с ним просто оставляю открытым, с помощью Android Monitor отслеживаю потребление памяти и оно постепенно возрастает. Хотя никаких действий не происходит (на первый взгляд). Хотелось бы получить совет именно по гайдам или статьям, учебникам по поиску утечек, чтобы впредь я смог искать утечки сам. Пишу на Java, использую Android Studio. Спасибо.

Comment: То, что потребление возрастает не показатель утечки, объекты постоянно создаются, даже если пользовательский код и не выполняется явно. Утечка - когда после того, как сборщик мусора отработал, остаются "не прибранными" классы, которые должны быть уничтожены. Для профилирования приложения Android Studio имеет довольно [внушительный набор инструментов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/528229/177345), которые дают полное представление о работе приложения (а за более год они были улучшены и добавлены новые). Трудность в том, что интерпретировать "показания" этих инструментов порой довольно сложно.

Comment: @pavloff, хотелось бы именно информацию по интерпретации и использованию этих инструментов)

Comment: В принципе, довольно внушительный раздел [гайда по Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/index.html) - *Profile Your App* целиком посвящен этому вопросу и вполне раскрывает тему. Конкретно [инструмент HPROF Viewer](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-hprof.html#display) имеет детектор утечек (вкладка *Analyzer Tasks* справа). Тема очень объемная и я, например, совершенно не готов писать, фактически, небольшую книгу об этом.  Повторю, что само по себе возрастание потребления памяти не является ее утечкой, пока GC справляется с этим.

Comment: @pavloff, он не справляется, через неделю (при неактивном приложении!) его вес увеличился в два раза(

Comment: Прямо мистика какая-то. Если приложение неактивно, то и памяти расти неоткуда. Видимо там всё же есть какой-то активный бекграунд процесс. И о какой памяти речь? У вас что, приложение неделю висит в оперативке и система его до сих пор не убила?

Comment: В Android studio 3.0 хорошо прокачали Android monitor -> Monitors для отслеживания потребления памяти и выявления кто именно ее потребляет.Там прям на графике потребления можно выделить участок и посмотреть какие процессы потребляют память