# Оптимизация статических переменных

Tags: android

Имеется приложение в котором около 10 `activity` и `service`'ов.

В коде каждого имеется установка текстов, положений переключателей, режимов и так далее через `SharedPreferences`.

Таким образом у меня получается, что в каждом Activity и service в начале кода, где объявляются "глобальные" переменные, имеется от 5 до 15-ти примерно таких строк:

```
public static final String APP_STORAGE = "AppStorageFile";
public static final String APP_STORAGE_MELODYMODE = "MelodyMode";
public static final String APP_STORAGE_USER_GOAL = "UserGoal";
...
```

Вообще, где-то на подсознательном уровне я предполагаю, что именно эти кучи названий параметров является причиной жуткого пожирания памяти и кучи лагов в моём приложении.

Я подозреваю, что это всё можно как-то упростить. Может быть убрать public static? Может быть их объявлять исключительно перед работой с ними? Однако во всех примерах их используют именно как: `public static final String xxx = "yyy";`

Прошу подсказать, является ли это причиной чрезмерного пожирания памяти и если да, то как можно выйти из такого положения?

Comment: причем здесь `SharedPreferences`, если вопрос по статическим переменным в активити? для чего вы их используете никак не влияет  на проблему в вашем вопросе

Comment: @pavlofff , если вы про теги, то понял, исправил.

Comment: Если у вас утечки памяти и лаги, то [нужно профилировать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/528229/177345) приложение, выяснять, что является их причиной. По одной вашей фразе - *Может быть убрать public static*, можно уже предположить, что их в вашем коде более, чем достаточно. Само по себе присутствие 20 переменных в классе не может являться причиной большого расхода памяти или, тем более, лагов. Однако со статиком в коде нужно быть внимательным, [при определенных условиях](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/debug/memoryleak.php) он может удерживать ненужный уже класс от утилизации GC.

Comment: Сама по себе идея статических имен к значениям используется для того, чтобы легче править код и исключить ошибки. То есть вам не надо в **каждом** классе писать одно и то же (да еще и статик), а надо создать статический класс `Constants`, к примеру, куда поместить все эти переменные и потом обращаться в любом классе через `Constants.APP_STORAGE` и подобные. Это исключит ошибки в именах и позволит, исправив в одном месте, поменять значение во всем проекте (а не править каждый класс и наделать ошибок).

Comment: Зачем вам 10 сервисов в приложении?почему бы не пользоваться одним? за исключением ситуаций, когда к примеру firebase создает свой собственный сервис.

Comment: @SviatVolkov , затем, что они запускаются при различных условиях и выполняют разную работу.

Comment: приведите пример

Comment: @SviatVolkov , мне кажется это не относится к данному вопросу, но не против поделится информацией. :) Но если конкретно, у меня есть `reciver`, 3 `fragmen`'a, 5 `activity` и 2 `Service`. Один `service` запускает одну мелодию в определённый промежуток времени, другой `service` запускает другую мелодию, но уже по нажатию. В любом случае и в `frgment`'ах, и в `Activity`, и в `Service` имеются, приведённые в вопросе, строки и моё "скрытие" такого разнообразия элементов отрицательно не повлияло на условия вопроса.