# android studio можно ли смотреть за работай эмулятора?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Есть ли инструмент в android studio, чтобы смотреть сколько памяти класс или метод и общая загрузка устройства приложением? Если нету, то как можно это делать?

Comment: В Android profiler нужного нет?

Comment: @Эникейщик, Ну да он подойдет. Для всего приложения. А там есть разделение на классы?

Comment: Вот чего не знаю, того не знаю.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/528229/177345

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Android Studio это можно сделать через profiler - memory. Там уже можно снять дамп памяти и смотреть нужную вам информацию

Comment: Там же можно смотреть по классам или методом, не только по приложению??

Comment: @chilo5432 любое приложение, которое можно дебажить, можно там просмотреть. Если хотети с плей маркета что-то посмотреть, то не получится.